# How can I create a new object without a form, using just URL parameters in a Rails friendly way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What would be the most rails friendly way to create a new object strictly from landing on a URL, bypassing the need for a form?

Suppose I have 3 models:

- Business
- Customer
- Rating

A business has many customers, and a customer has one rating.

Example: How would you rate your meal at XYZ Restaurant? 1, 2, or 3? (Each of those being separate links that would save a score of 1/2/3)

What will my rating#new and rating#create methods & routes need to look like to accomplish this?

I was able to get it working by creating a totally new method which you can see below:

Example URL: abc.com/ratings/:customer_token/:score

```
def rate
@customer = Customer.find_by_token(params[:customer_token])
@business = @customer.business
unless @customer.ratings.exists?
  @rating = @customer.ratings.new
  @rating.customer_id = @customer.id
  @rating.business_id = @business.id
  @rating.score = params[:score].to_i
  @rating.save
  if @rating.save
    redirect_to :action => 'thanks'
  end
end
```

end

While the above works, I know it isn't a good way to do it. Would love some advice!

**Edit: I want to make it clear that the links I'd like to generate will be from an email client, so I can't use ruby logic there or any sort of javascript.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you credit for coming up with a solution that on the surface works, but I can see a problem... if it's actually a `link_to` that you've created that creates a `GET` action, then you could end up with unexpected postings from web crawlers!

Imagine Google's spiders following every link on your site... they will find links to a customer, they will find links to rating, and by following the rating link, they'll create a rating!  This is why actions that create, change, or delete data should never be behind `GET`actions.

Consider using `button_to` helpers which create buttons that essentially do a `POST` (and modify your routes to accept `POST` to your show url)

```
button_to('Rate 1', customer_token: @customer.token, rating: 1)
```

I guess a customer belongs to a business? `@business = @customer.business`. If a customer rates two businesses, there are two customer records?

Also, you don't need the first `@rating.save` ... the second one is a repeat of the save. But that's a minor issue.

Comment: Correct - that's why I'd like to obfuscate the customer IDs into tokens like this: @customer.token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand, @customer.business].join)[0..15] These links would only be present in emails sent to customers, and tokens or links won't be present on the site for Google to mess around with. Though you do make me question if email clients can/will visit links on their own, which would mess up a lot of things.

Comment: Ah, right. No, the use of tokens in email links has a long history and I've not heard of sign-up links being followed automatically.  I'm a lot more comfortable with what you're doing based on that. :)

Comment: Saw your edit - thanks. I did some quick googling with button_to and found someone else trying to do something similar using it. That advice said to use a get request. So I'm still stuck on that. Thanks for the rating.save advice as well - didn't even realize that. And yes, a customer is unqiue to a business. 10 businesses could have the same email address as a customer, and 10 customer records would exist. There's some reasoning for that, but the 150 characters I have left won't let me explain how the app works :P Thank you!

Comment: Like Fermat's Last Theorem. The proof's too big to fit in the margin. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your proposed method is risky is it nests all your parameters in the URL get stream without verifying via the post stream. Someone could type in something rediculous in your URL and add something odd, like `abc.com/ratings/[legit customer token]/55` and your code would put a rating of 55 out of 3 in your database.

You could still use a form, with hidden variables, to create the rating. You can still have 1, 2, and 3, be the content of links (like buttons) to submit that form.

```
#in your view
<% 3.times do |i| %>
  <%= form_for @rating, action: :rate do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :score, value: i %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :customer_id, value: @customer.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :business_token, value: @business.id %>
    <%= f.submit i %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
#in your controller
def rate
  @rating = Rating.new(rating_params)
  if @rating.save
    #handle success
  else 
    #handle error
  end
end

private
  def rating_params
    params.require(:rating).permit(:rating, :customer_id, :business_id)
  end
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think about preventing a rating of 55.

The reason I'd like the URL to do all of the work is because these links will be sent to customers via email. I'd like to have a high conversion rate on the actual ratings, and in the testing I've done, making it one click from the email client is exponentially better. If I introduce any sort of form or second click, I'll lose a significant amount of conversions, and those are essential to me. I'm assuming I could confirm a 1-5 rating only in the controller before saving though which should, in theory prevent that?

Comment: Since it's in emails and not a page, that makes sense.

I definitely suggest verifying the contents of the params before saving, then.

Answer (score 0):

The only option (aside from an AJAX call) would be to use the [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper, with a method `POST`:

```
link_to 'Rate', ratings_path(score: 1, customer_token: 123), method: :post
```

Although this will not look like a form in your codebase, Rails will utilise [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) and will generate a form using JavaScript.

Your controllers will just have to use the `params` to find the appropriate `Customer` and add a `rating` with the score to it.

Hope that helps!